# Compare dates in a loop

Tags: vba, date, excel

I have a loop that goes and check an entire column of dates. 
And i want that loop to check wether or not it is still the same day as the previous cell (-1). Datas are organized like this :

```
    ID     DATE       TIME     PRICE       QUANTITY    NBE
```

I tried already with both following code as an argument for my loop, but it does not work... Dates are in column B, and are formatting like follow: dd:mm:yyyy

That's what my new code looks like

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim lngFirstRow As Long, lngLastRow As Long, cRow As Long, lngNextDestRow As Long
Dim jbs As Date
Dim shSrc As Worksheet, shDest As Worksheet

Set shSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("2008P1")
Set shDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheeet2")


With shSrc

    lngFirstRow = 2
    lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", after:=.Cells.Cells(1), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
    lngNextDestRow = 2



    For cRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow Step 1
        jbs = .Cells(cRow, 2)

        If jbs <> .Cells(cRow - 1, 2).Value Then
            .Rows(cRow).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("A" & lngNextDestRow)
            .Rows(cRow + 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=shDest.Range("A" & lngNextDestRow + 1)
            lngNextDestRow = lngNextDestRow + 2

        End If
    Next cRow
 End With
End Sub
```

Thanks to your response Branislav I edited it like this ;) And it seems to work well.

Comment: 1. Can there be more than 2 occurences of one date? 2. The **next day** will always be next calendar day?

Comment: It's a sheet full of trade orders from one specific stock over one year, the sheets i have to extract the datas from are 500K+ rows long.  I only need the first two opening trade of every trading day
And no the next will not always be the following calendar day, because markets are not opened saturdays and sunday, and exceptionnal events such as december 25th and so on

Comment: The dates are sorted from oldest to newest, right?

Comment: newest are at the bottom

Comment: What if a date is in the data only once? Do you want just one row to be extracted for this date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will extract 2 rows of exactly same dates and then move to other date. **Will not work if a date is in the database just once**.

```
Sub FindSameDatesCopy2Rows()
'Check if the 2 subsequent dates are the same and extract the whole rows to other sheet
'Then move to other date and again check and extract. Repeat.

    Dim lngNextDestRow As Long
    Dim shDest As Worksheet
    Dim bolExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim jbs As Variant
    Dim cRow As Long
    Dim cRow2 As Long
    Dim rngNextDay As Range
    Dim lngFirstRow  As Long
    Dim lngLastRow  As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    lngNextDestRow = 2 'change to your situation
    lngFirstRow = 1 'change to your situation
    lngLastRow = 19 'change to your situation
    Set shDest = Worksheets(3) 'change to your situation

    With Worksheets(2) 'change to your situation
        For cRow = lngFirstRow To lngLastRow Step 1
            If bolExitLoop And cRow = lngFirstRow Then Exit For 'need to set this to exit infinite loop, because .Find will wrap again and again
            jbs = .Cells(cRow, 2)
            If jbs = .Cells(cRow + 1, 2) Then
                .Rows(cRow & ":" & cRow + 1).Copy shDest.Rows(lngNextDestRow)
                lngNextDestRow = lngNextDestRow + 2
                For cRow2 = cRow To lngLastRow
                    'find the next day, any day
                    Set rngNextDay = .Range("B:B").Find("*", after:=.Cells(cRow2, 2))

                    'compare if the day is different than that we already done
                    If rngNextDay <> jbs Then
                        'set the row for next loop
                        cRow = rngNextDay.Row - 1
                        'need to set this to exit infinite loop, because .Find will wrap again and again
                        bolExitLoop = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next cRow2
            End If

        Next cRow
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot sir!
I changed the if and used your code and it works like a charm!

Comment: I edited above the final code i came up with thanks to your last advices ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that works for me:

```
Sub test()
Dim dTest As Date
Dim j As Long
Dim rCount As Long

j = 1

For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    rCount = 0
    j = i
    dTest = Cells(i, 1).Value

    While dTest = Cells(j, 1).Value
        'Here should be the code which tells what to do
        'when the date is the same
        j = j + 1
        rCount = rCount + 1
    Wend

    i = i + rCount - 1
Next i
End Sub
```

When I have the dates like this:

[image]

It returns this, when you add some msgboxes:

[image]

I hope I could help you

greetings
Amnney

Comment: I tried using your advices, but i still get no result :s